# AngularJS - Data binding default value of html select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I would like to 'data bind' the default value of a html/jade select. Here is my select:

```
select#title.form-control(ng-model='newClient.title')
    option(ng-repeat='title in titles', ng-selected='$first') {{title}}
```

The problem here is that if I don't touch the select, my newClient.title will be set as undefined and not the first title value. How can I do that without setting a default value in my controller?

Comment: How about `ng-selected="newClient.titles[0]"`

Comment: ng-selected is a boolean, newClient.title is a string... I don't understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ahh, nvm, just saw you had the repeat on `option` elements - why are you not using `ng-options`?

Comment: B ecause I'm new to angularJS and I don't have the right reflex :o) Let me try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ng-init` directive.

`ng-init="newClient.title = titles[0]"`

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/9nsTd/1/)

in jade format:

```
select#title.form-control(ng-model='newClient.title',ng-init="newClient.title = titles[0]")
    option(ng-repeat='title in titles', ng-value="title") {{title}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use ng-options to define the options, and then simply specify the ng-model for the first element. You don't have to worry about an ng-init.

```
<select ng-options="title for title in titles" ng-model='titles[0]'></select>
```

For reference, there's some pretty good documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).